# Error when returning a variable/array from Ruby method

Tags: ruby

In my capistrano task, I'm calling the `superfunction` method. Unfortunately it's throwing an `Unexpected Return` error. I need to grab the output from the `superfunction` method in order to parse it further within my task.

```
def superfunction(cmd_type, command, client)
    run "#{command}" do |channel, stream, data|
        hostname = "#{channel[:host]}".tr('"','')
        result = "#{data}".to_s.strip
        return hostname, result
    end

end


task :gather, :roles => :hosts do
...
   servername, redhat_version = superfunction("redhat_version", "cat /etc/redhat-release", client)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is being generated because your block is being called after the method has returned (possibly capistrano stores it internally). As a simple workaround, you can get the variables you want by using a block:

```
def superfunction(cmd_type, command, client)
  run "#{command}" do |channel, stream, data|
    hostname = "#{channel[:host]}".tr('"','')
    result = "#{data}".to_s.strip
    yield(hostname, result)
  end
end

task :gather, :roles => :hosts do
  superfunction("redhat_version", "cat /etc/redhat-release", client) do |servername, redhat_version|
    # Use servername and redhat_version here
  end
end
```